# Бессмертный Broadcast Receiver без уведомления

Tags: android

Всем привет! Пишу виджет, который проверяет состояние Wi-Fi (если состояние Фаи изменилось - Broadcast Receiver реагирует и я получаю результат), но происходит это не долго может пол дня, а может минут 30 - все зависит от системы андроид, она сама решает когда и кого убить.
Можно сделать бессмертного слушателя официально с неубираемым уведомлением - но для мелкого некчёмного приложения - это не вариант.

Как мне лучше реализовать, через AlarmManager?
Если это единственный вариант то посоветуйте какое время перевызова выставить чтобы аларм вызвался раньше чем система убьет процесс.
Но и в то же время не так часто, чтобы приложение не кушало батарею.

Comment: правильный broadcastReceiver по умолчанию является вечным. Проблема у вас в реализации, вы что-то сделали не правильно

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Comment: Спасибо, действительно помогло, оказывается я неправильно считал принцип работы.

Comment: Надо было прописывать действия не в объявлении ресивера
` 
    public BroadcastReceiver WifiReceiver =  new BroadcastReceiver(){
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
          //это код не работает
        }
    };
` 
` public class WidgetPack extends AppWidgetProvider {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
        //а здесь работает
    }
} `

Comment: Извините, не понял как код писать в коментариях

Answer (score 2):

Достаточно задекларировать `<receiver>` с флагом `android:exported=true` и ресивер будет жить вечно вне зависимости от состояния приложения. [Документация тынц](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/receiver-element.html)